# What Email API Salesforce use for their platform

Tags: email

We know, Salesforce has a lots of Application on its platform.

I would like to know,for their `platform(Sales cloud, Service Cloud)` ,  what `Mail API(SMTP, POP3, MAPI)` they use to send emails to their customers.

Do we have any official documentation for this?

Comment: why do you need these details? I dont think they publish these sort of information.

Answer (score 0):

I think they support multiple APIs but what they exactly use varies with the feature.

SMTP is definitely used as we have SMTP relaying. We have some restrictions in using POP3 and IMAP with outlook so not sure about it. Please raise a case with salesforce with your exact query.